# TYPO3 error after dump-autoload: call to undefined method

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-11.x

I have a running TYPO3 project running on Docker windows with WSL2 Ubuntu subsystem.

I have changed some TCA columns in my custom TYPO3 extension, the project still running good until I run this command (was trying to update):

```
composer dump-autoload -a
```

This is the result error that shows in powershell :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Composer\Repository\PlatformRepository::isPlatformPackage() in
> .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Composer/PackageArtifactBuilder.php:75
> Stack trace:
> #0 .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php(1111): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Composer\PackageArtifactBuilder->isComposerDependency()
> #1 .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php(1197): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager->convertConfigurationForGraph()
> #2 .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php(1085): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager->buildDependencyGraph()
> #3 .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Composer/PackageArtifactBuilder.php(138):
> TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager->sortPackageStatesConfigurationByDependency()
> #4 .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Co in .../web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Composer/PackageArtifactBuilder.php
> on line 75

I don't understand why this command has broke my project and now I'm stuck.

I have already tried to rebuild all the container with composer down and up. No results.

Comment: Which version of Composer do you use? What else did you try to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is that i should excute the composer inside the tool container of this project.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned method was [added with Composer 2.0](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/a1e1cd8fa4047a4f65abd853ccccc87c92733bba) which is required at runtime [since TYPO3v11](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/67371). (Later [bumped to Composer 2.1](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/71083))

So you need to make sure that you use at least Composer 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you please send me how i should use it ? you mean command is wrong ?
I have already enable the Composer V2 in Docker console > Settings > General > Use Docker Compose V2

Comment: Docker Compose != Composer. You need to update your [Composer Installation](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: Thank you Peter,

my Composer is already updated when i run this command :

docker-compose --version


i get >> Docker Compose version v2.2.3

Comment: Once more: Docker Compose is **not** Composer

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm new to this environment, i will update it now :)